# HTML5 video fullscreen seek

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is there a way to capture seek event while video is playing in a fullscreen mode?

I am running separate audio and video streams and I need to sync audio and video when seek position changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *timeupdate* event:

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    //do some magic here…
})
```